# 1 ViewController and 2 XIBs for 2 orientations, how?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller

One ViewController is shared by two XIBs, i.e. there are one XIB for horizontal layout and another one for vertical layout. Both XIBs are linked to the same ViewController, i.e.:

```
HiScoreViewController.h
HiScoreViewController.m
HiScoreViewController-Horizontal.xib
HiScoreViewController-Vertical.xib
```

The question is how I can (re)load the corresponding XIB in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` ?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest it would be good to use different views instead of different xibs & you can hide/ unhide views based on orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different views in One View Controller. Can change the Views based on the Orientation.